# Can't send base64 encoded picture to remote

Tags: ios, curl, lua

I need your help. Got an image base64 encoded, trying to send base64 data to remote, but my code do not send it because base64 ecoded pic is too big.
using ios 14 + lua + curl

```
local b64 = "picture_encoded_base64"

local handle = io.popen([[""curl -i -X 'POST'
    'http://server ip:port'
    -H 'Accept: application/json'
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
    -d '{"cap_type": "3d", "image_base64": "]]..b64..[["}'""]]) 
    prequest = handle:read("*a") 
    handle:close()

log(prequest)
```

Comment: FYI, code blocks are done with triple backticks (` character), not triple quotes (' character).

Comment: What's the purpose of double double quotes in the beginning and the end of the command?

Comment: Try providing POST data as a file, not as a command line argument.